# What is this default gray circle

Tags: unity-game-engine

I apologize in advance for such a basic question. I haven't been able to find anything online referring to this. I'm probably just not using the right search terms, but I don't know what this is called.

This is zoomed out showing my model which is a large building, and what appears to be a default sort of terrain or horizon. I can't interact with it. What is it and how do I get rid of it?

[image]

This view is a little closer and the scene has a sky box applied
[image]

This view is much closer at an angle showing the skybox. You can see the gray circle cutting the skybox off at the horizon.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what it looks like in wireframe mode?

Answer (score 1):

This might be the far clipping plane of the camera coming into effect.

Clipping planes are two (near and far) planes from the camera's origin, away. Anything near than the near is culled, anything further than the far is culled.

If you're using a very wide angle camera, you might get this sort of round clipping effect on a far plane.

Try setting the far plane's value to a much higher number, to see if that helps/solves the problem.

Select your Main Camera in the Hierarchy, and adjust the Clipping plane values in the Inspector, about half way down... here...

[image]

Comment: Good thought. I'm familiar with clipping planes and adjusting that has no effect. It is related to something like that though. Its not an object. Something to do with player settings, the camera, or something similar.

Comment: Doh. I dunno. Been fighting all sorts of z-battle issues with Unity, and layering issues, last few days. Not this, though.